# get_the_category_list() does not give me all my categories

Tags: categories

I am trying to use `<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>` in my `footer.php` file to display my categories. On the home page, this function is showing only two categories and in inner single posts it shows that post's related category. In pages, this tag shows nothing.
I have even tried to use `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after each `WP_Query`, but that did not help.

How do I make this work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_the_category_list()` shows categories that have been assigned to a particular post/page.

If you want a list of **all** categories you've defined then you should use `wp_list_categories()` ([Link to Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories))